# How do I connect to a Netcool / Omnibus “Object Server” using JayDeBeApi module along with SAP Sybase JDBC drivers (jconn4.jar) in Python3?

Tags: jdbc, python-3.5

I am new to python programming. I'm trying to connect to a Netcool Object Server using Python3, I am using JayDeBeApi module along with SAP Sybase JDBC drivers (jconn4.jar)

following is the sample script:

```
import jaydebeapi
server="xxx"
database="xx"
user="xx"
password="xx"

jclassname='com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver'
url='jdbc:sybase:Tds://'+server+'/'+database
driver_args=[url,user,password]
jars="path/jconn4.jar"

conn=jaydebeapi.connect(jclassname,driver_args,jars)
curs = conn.cursor()
curs.execute("select * from status")
curs.fetchall()`
```

when I am executing the script it showing an error as follows

```
File "sample.py", line 12, in <module>
    conn=jaydebeapi.connect(jclassname,driver_args,jars)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jaydebeapi/__init__.py", line 381, in connect
    jconn = _jdbc_connect(jclassname, url, driver_args, jars, libs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jaydebeapi/__init__.py", line 199, in _jdbc_connect_jpype
    return jpype.java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(url, *dargs)
RuntimeError: No matching overloads found. at native/common/jp_method.cpp:117
```

if anyone successfully connected to a Netcool Object Server using JayDeBeApi module in Python3? please share the sample script

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The url format you specified is not correct. The below works for me.

```
url = jdbc:sybase:Tds:++hostname:++dbport/++dbname
```

e.g

```
conn = jaydebeapi.connect('com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver', ['jdbc:sybase:Tds:hostA:8888/db1','root',''],['path/jconn4.jar'])
```